# Existence of a cycle of length $2^k$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, open-problem

I was   given a question which asks me to show that if each vertex of a graph has degree$\geq 3$, then it has a cycle whose length is some power of $2$. I have been able to show that  it has a even cycle.it can be shown either by induction or by considering a maximal path. but I have not been able to progress beyond that. can some one help me?

Comment: This is a well-known unsolved problem, called the Erdős–Gyárfás conjecture. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gy%C3%A1rf%C3%A1s_conjecture

Comment: This is totally off-topic, but in case you solve it, you might want to write an email to Ronald Graham and politely ask if there is a chance to get the price money, Paul Erdős offered.

Comment: In other word the OP was trolled by his friend :)